# Error: Invalid Outside Procedure

Tags: vb.net

I need to write a program thats gonna print the numbers from 1 to 100 and for numbers devidable with 3 print "d3", numbers devideable with 5 print "d5", and if devideable with both then print "d53", but in VB I get an error for the second line "for I=1 to 100": invalid outside procedure"!

```
Dim I As Integer 

For I = 1 To 100 
  If I Mod 3 And I Mod 5 Then Print "d53" 

  Else: If I Mod 3 Then Print "d3" 

  Else: If I Mod 5 Then Print "d5"

 Next I 
end sub
```

Comment: Do you have this code inside a Sub or Function? I.E. `Sub Main .... your code .... End Sub` I can see an End Sub but there is no Sub in your code above

Comment: Is this inside a `Sub Main()`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is outside of every Function or Sub defined in your class or module.
Your code should be enclosed by a Sub or Function (And looking at your lonely `End Sub` I suppose that you need a Sub

```
Sub Main
    Dim I As Integer 

    For I = 1 To 100 
        Console.Write(I)
        If (I Mod 3) = 0 And (I Mod 5) = 0 Then 
            Console.WriteLine"=d53"

        Else If (I Mod 3) = 0 Then 
            Console.Write("=d3")

        Else If (I Mod 5) = 0 Then 
            Console.Write("=d5")
        End if
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next I 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (i Mod 3) = 0 And (i Mod 5) = 0 Then 
    Print ...
ElseIf (i Mod 3) = 0 Then 
    Print ...
ElseIf (i Mod 5) = 0 Then 
    Print ...
End If
```

Comment: it still gives me compile error: invalid outside procedure, with highlighting the second line, i changed all the lines with (i mod #)=0